# Flex : How to set a flex control focusable when it is disabled?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, focusable

How to get focus for a disabled flex control.

When a flex control is set with enable=false ,the control is not focusable and hence is not read by a screen reader.

When a user tab's it should also go to the disabled controls.

wanted to know how can we overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure disabled means that the control is not usable; which means it cannot accept focus.

If you can elaborate on your use case, perhaps we can offer a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually working for physically challenged people to use the software. Given the scenario all focusable components are read by the screen reader but non focusable components are not read. Hence they are not accesible to these people. The components are non focusable based on bussiness logic.

Comment: Maybe you should update the label on the control to say "disabled"?

Comment: Why do physically challenged people need to know the component is there?  Especially if it can't accept focus or be used.

Comment: Good thought though ,but this software will be used both by physically challenged as well as normal users and has to have consistent look for normal users.

So if not the answer i welcome idea's which i can try..Thanks for all the responses